# Facebook graph api not returning all public fields

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used to call facebook page node with feed and posts edges and it return all the fields including comments ect.., but now I don't know what happen, it just return 3 fields (message, created_time and id), I'v tested it with the API explorer, postman and my app (an R package), did Facebook change something ? even in the search API it used to return the category of the page when I search for pages, but it dosent anymore..

Comment: please add your code or at least the exact api call. did you forget to ask for the fields?

Comment: _https://graph.facebook.com/FatherOfNation/posts?access_token=""_ 
`"data": [
        {
            "message": "There are two days in the year that we can not do anything, yesterday and tomorrow. - Mahatama Gandhi",
            "created_time": "2017-06-29T16:21:32+0000",
            "id": "173835512636336_1606557689364104"
        },`

Comment: I didn't use to ask for fields, I receive all fields by default

Comment: always add relevant stuff to the question, not in comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading

Check out the section "Choosing Fields", you have to ask for fields you want to get, else you will only get some default ones.

Comment: I was receiving all fields by default, I don't what changed, I had to request all fields now

Comment: Another data point, I'm seeing the exact same thing. Used to give me all fields, now just doesn't. Very strange.

Comment: that´s not strainge if you don´t ask for the fields. it is only strange that you got all fields before, because declarative fields got implemented a long time ago. if you don´t get fields even though you specifically request them, then maybe they are deprecated.